# SQL : Query() where COL = int instead of string ? (pictures + code inside)

Tags: android, sql, database, integer

Here is an explanation of my problem.
**Description of the app :** i want the application to display a listview with different content depending on the button clicked by the user. To do so, there is in my database a column with a number (1 or 2), i want the click on button 1 to display only elements where this number is 1 and so on.

**A.** when the user click on a button (called button1), it opens a new activity (ResultListViewActivity) and send an integer called "myVariable" via putExtra.

```
private OnClickListener listener_button1 = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent t = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                ResultListViewActivity.class);
        t.putExtra("myVariable", 1);
        startActivity(t);

    }

};
```

**B.** in the ResultListViewActivity, there is a method (findNameInTable) which uses this integer as an input:

```
private void displayListView() {

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int myVariable = bundle.getInt("myVariable");

    Cursor c = dbHelper.findNameInTable(myVariable);
    // the desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.COL_NAME,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_COMMENTS, };
    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.comments, };
    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    // as well as the layout information
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.poi_info, c,
            columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

**C.** this method findNameInTable() is defined in my DatabaseAdapter class as follows :

```
    public Cursor findNameInTable(int myVariable) {
    c = myDatabase
            .query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { COL_NAME , COL_COMMENTS }, COL_CAT1 = myVariable,
                    new String[] { Integer.toString(myVariable) }, null,
                    null, null);
    return c;
}
```

I want this method to return a cursor in which there would be contents of COL_NAME (column name) and COL_COMMENTS for every line of the database where COL_CAT1 = myVariable (i.e 1 if i click on button1 for example).

I tried to turn my int into a string using Integer.toString(myVariable) but it's still not working. Also, on top of my activity, I defined COL_CAT1 as follows :

```
    public static final String COL_CAT1 = "cat1";
```

I really hope it's clear enough and someone will help me make this work, I really start to feel desperate with this thing...

Thanks in advance !

edit: posted code instead of pictures

Comment: You do realize that no one wants to retype your code, and that by using screenshots instead of text, you're almost forcing them to do that, yes?

Comment: Sorry for this, edited my post.

Comment: @Phalanx use COL_CAT1+"=?" instead of COL_CAT1=myVariable

Comment: @JaiSoni : it works, no more error message. My app is still not working but it might come from something else, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Query as :

```
 c=mydatabase.query(
            DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] { COL_NAME,COL_COMMENTS },
            COL_CAT1 + "=?" ,
            new String[] { Integer.toString(myVariable) }, null, null, null
        );
```